# Using NFTStorage WebApi (upload) with some problem and get an error "Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error)."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httprequest, content-type, content-disposition

And i use Postman to test is Body using "form-data" and "key" is file "value" is upload ur file, Headers u should set "Key" is Authorization "value" is Bearer yourapikey from NFT storage  account. And this can work!

and here is mycode it will got an error "Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error)."
Can find the document in https://nft.storage/api-docs/

```
string path = "file.json"
const string uri = "https://api.nft.storage";
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

var imagename = path.Split(@"\").ToList().Last();
var fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(System.IO.File.OpenRead(path));
ContentDispositionHeaderValue hd = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue(@"form-data");
hd.Name = "file";
hd.FileName = "metadata.json";
fileStreamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = hd;
fileStreamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
form.Add(fileStreamContent, "file", imagename);
form.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer yourapikey");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri+"/upload", form);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return responseBody;
}
```

Comment: A multipart form is a mime attachment that starts with a new line with two dashes.  See example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true.  I can't tell exactly what is failing.  Either the MIME is not formatted correctly or the default HTTP headers in c# are not matching the headers in Postman. Is postman working from same computer and same account? Inside VS you are not automatically an ADMIN.  Try starting VS by right clicking VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: I find the problem is that
`hd.Name = @"""file""";`
`hd.FileName = @"""metadata.json""";`
The Api have to add  this " char in string ....

Comment: The double quote in HTML has to be escaped. See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem is that

`hd.Name = @"""file""";`

`hd.FileName = @"""metadata.json""";`

The Api have to add this " char in string